# SCSS temp file not compiling to css

Tags: html, css, sass

I am facing a weird issue. I have been working on sass which was working fine until today when I created a new temp file named `_grid.scss` and included it into the `main.scss` file which is actually a parent file. When I added some piece of code inside `_grid.scss` it is not compiling it into the CSS, instead, it works fine when I add the same piece of code in `main.scss` file.

**main.scss**

```
@import "abstracts/functions";
@import "abstracts/mixins";
@import "abstracts/variables";

@import "base/base";
@import "base/animations";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/utilities";

@import "components/button";

@import "layout/grid"; // this is the file which I have created and included
@import "layout/header";

@import "pages/home";
```

**_grid.scss**

```
.row{
    max-width:114rem;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Just to verify: Is `_grid.scss` in the `layout` directory?

Comment: @beltouche yes.

Comment: Check file permissions?

Comment: @beltouche it is same as other files

Comment: The code in _header.scss is transpiling correctly?

Comment: And again, just to be certain: You know it's not in the generated CSS, as opposed to you're just not seeing the expected effects?

Comment: @symlink it is not working as it should

Comment: It is one step behind. For example, if I set the color pink and then second time I set the color green then the browser renders pink, not green then again I set the color brown then browser renders as green.

Comment: @beltouche in the `main.scss` it works fine and the new code added to the `style.css`. But this isn't the case when I add code in the temp files

Comment: @ZainFarooq are you doing hard refreshes every time? The browser will cache the CSS files otherwise.

Comment: @symlink I have set the `live-server`

Comment: @ZainFarooq if you drop the grid.scss into header.scss, what happens?

Comment: @symlink Hmm, I have deleted the `_grid.scss` and added the code into `_header.scss` and it's not working there as well

Comment: @ZainFarooq if it's transpiling correctly, but not showing up, it may be being overridden, or the selectors are not targeting what you think they are. Did you check in the inspector to make sure they're not overwritten?

Comment: @symlink It works fine in `main.scss` and also appends the new code to `style.css`

Comment: I have removed the auto-save mode of the editor and it starts working fine. But I am curious about how can I make it work in the auto-save mode?